# Jekyll & GitHub Pages not building properly at localhost

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I downloaded GitHub page as .zip to my PC so I can edit it locally. I installed:

- Ruby 2.7+Devkit from this webpage
  https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
- Jekyll (with bundler) according to their tutorial:
  https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/
- GitHub pages gem according to this tutorial
  https://kbroman.org/simple_site/pages/local_test.html

However when serving the webpage using `jekyll serve` and visiting http://localhost:4000 I only saw list of directories like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpjpP.png. So I wanted to execute `bundle install` but it told me no Gemfile was found so I created one as a copy of Gemfile from default new Jekyll project. I replaced the `minima` template for `jekyll-theme-cayman` which is the theme of GitHub pages and then changed the jekyll version to work with it. Then I successfully  `bundle install` and `bundle exec jekyll serve` however I still saw only the list of directories. When I checked the `_site` subfolder, I saw no generated `.html` as were in the new generated Jekyll project. I spent fair amount of time figuring...

Answer (score 0):

While the answer is so simple. In Gemfile copied from the empty generated project, one must comment out the jekyll version and uncomment the github pages line. If I read the file instead of googling aimlessly what to do... I would like to keep this Q&A as I did not come across exactly the same thing when googling, so it might be helpful to somebody new to Jekyll.